# How to do not break a word after the hyphen?

Tags: html, css

I am using css break-word:

```
<p style="word-wrap: break-word; ">blablablablablablablablablablablabla-blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla</p>
```

and as you see, my word is breaking after the hyphen `-` :

blablablablablablablablablablablabla-blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla

But this is not what I want, I like to break the word only at the end of the line.

Comment: why not    word-break: break-all;

Comment: While I'm sure the answer is out there and this didn't require a new post, I'm not sure it deserved a down-vote.

Comment: @Leothelion Thank you, this is working!

Comment: I posted as answer.. please have a look.ty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to break the word only at the end of the line then use

```
word-break: break-all;
```

rather then break-word.. Hope this will help.

Demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kqu7w4xc/1/)

Answer (score 4):

`word-break` will make your dreams come true.

```html
<p style="word-break: break-all; ">blablablablablablablablablablablabla-blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla</p>
```

Answer (score 4):

There is actually a character called "[non-breaking hyphen](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2011/index.htm)". If you are able to use that, it won't break at that character and you do not need a CSS work-around. The HTML notation of that special hyphen is `&#8209;`, you can use it just like any other special character, e.g. the ampersand "&" (`&amp;`) or the circular bullet point "•" (`&bull;`).

```html
<p style="word-wrap: break-word;">blablablablablablablablablablablabla&#8209;blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla</p>
```

Additional note: this is also helpful outside the internet, e.g. for usage in office software. In MS Word/Powerpoint you can enter a non-breaking hyphen by using one of the following shortcuts: `Ctrl + Shift + -` or `Alt + 8 2 0 9` (hold the Alt key and enter all digits using the num block).

Comment: never heard of this. Nice insight.